# dsm-750: how do I get it to refresh its media?

Tags: network-shares, media-center-extender

How do you get the DSM-750 to update its media from network folders (e.g. files contained on the network on a DNS-323 for example) more quickly?  It seems like it doesn't perform this operation automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar experience on my PS3 with media on my DNS-323, but I suspect the problem is actually related to the UPnP media server on the DNS-323 not immediately refreshing as opposed to the device accessing the media.  Does that line up with your symptoms?  On the DNS-323's management page for the UPnP media server there is a "Refresh" button, although I have found even that doesn't "immediately" update.  It sometimes takes some time.

Comment: @JMD: useful input... let me check.